# Why does GitHub show me a number of commits different from git rev-list?

Tags: git, github

When I check my GitHub repo, it shows me a number of commits much lower than what I get when I run the following command locally on my machine:

```sh
git rev-list --count HEAD
```

I am getting a number 160 but GitHub only shows 89.
Also when I run

```sh
git rev-parse HEAD@{159}
```

It seems not to find the index.
Is there something I'm missing?
*Update*
There are no merges on this repository yet.

Comment: I think this comes from merges check with `git rev-list --count --no-merges HEAD`

Comment: [Ôrel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4605105/%c3%94rel) I actually tried this earlier but it seems to print out exactly the same thing without the ```--no-merges``` option. Also I have not merged any changes in the repository. Perhaps I should update my question.

Comment: Can you point us at your github repository?

Comment: Where exactly is github showing the number of commits?

Comment: The number of commits is visible on the top right corner of the box showing source files.
I can't post images on stackoverflow yet

Comment: The `@{<number>}` syntax is for reflogs and has no direct correlation with the number of commits in the repository. You could have 1000 reflog entries and 2 commits, or 1000 commits and 2 reflog entries, for instance. The most likely reason for the discrepancy in counts is that your `HEAD` and repository are "ahead of" GitHub's copy.